# Symfony2 twig template is not updated after user registration

Tags: php, symfony, twig, registration, fosuserbundle

I have in my symfony2 application a registration modal which is working fine except for the template which is not updated in time but after one refresh.

When I successfully register in my application, the page is reloaded and I am connected in my app (I can see it in the Symfony debugger) but I can still see the "login" link in my header. and flash messages are not displayed (success or failure are the same).

Here is the twig code for the header:

```
    {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">
                <span class="menulink">Log out</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#registerModal">
                <span class="menulink">Register</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
```

Here is my `registerController`

```
class RegistrationStandardUserController extends Controller
{
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
            $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
            $user = new StandardUser();
            //Form creation based on my user entity
            $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationStandardUserType::class, $user);
            
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $user       ->setEnabled(true);
                $em         ->persist($user);
                $em         ->flush();
                if (!$user) {
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
                } else {
                    $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Félicitation '.$user->getFirstName().', vous êtes inscrit');
                    $this->authenticateUser($user);
                }
            }else if($form->isSubmitted() && !$form->isValid()){
                $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Il y a une erreur dans le formulaire d\'inscription');
            }
        
        return $this->render('UserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
    
    private function authenticateUser(StandardUser $user)
    {
        $discriminator = $this->get('pugx_user.manager.user_discriminator');
        $discriminator->setClass('UserBundle\Entity\StandardUser', true);
        $this->container->get('fos_user.security.login_manager')->loginUser($this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name'),$user);
    }
}
```

The modal is inserted like that in my template:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        {{ render(controller('UserBundle:RegistrationStandardUser:Register', {'request': app.request})) }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

I can't fine the issue. Could it be the way I insert the form in my template using `{{ render(controller('UserBundle:RegistrationStandardUser:Register', {'request': app.request})) }}` ?

I'm using `fosUserBundle` and `pugxMultiUser` for the user administration but I'm not sure that is relevant to understand the issue here.

Comment: Have you take a look to erro logs or profiler errors ?

Comment: I'm not sure of "IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED", this isn't "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" ?

Comment: Take a look to https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#flash-messages for your flash Messages !

Comment: @MathieuDormeval Thanks for your response. I just checked my error logs and I don't have much beside some javascript files not found. I will try the "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" in my template and let you know the result. You may be right, I don't realy get the difference ... :/

Comment: For the flash messages, I suppose it is the same problem as the header not updated because as soon as I refresh the page, my header is updated and I get my flash messages.

Comment: why are you using flash messages if you don't need to persist them until the next request?

Comment: about the `is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED")` that return `false`, that's because the security listener was already executed (before the controller).

Comment: a good practice is to redirect the user after any POST request.

Comment: @Federkun I think I understand but I not sure about how to do it. When I do it  after the authenticateUser(); using " return $this->redirectToRoute('site_homepage'); " , I get a An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Error when rendering "[...]" (Status code is 302).")